# What is the most intuitive way to pull an int from an array?

Tags: java, arrays, function, oop, object

So, I have an object in a class called "arrays":

```
static arrays VideoGame = new arrays(arrays.product[9], arrays.price[9]);
```

and a function:

```
public static void getPrice(int price){

    System.out.println("The cost is: " + price);

}
```

In my main file I call that function like this:

```
arrays.getPrice(arrays.price[9]);
```

Is there anything like

```
arrays.getPrice(VideoGame.price);
```

that lets you actually use the VideoGame object with the function?

EDIT: I forgot to say that "arrays" is a class I made with functions that create arrays.

Comment: What is `arrays`? I bet it's not a predefined class in Java.

Comment: Side note: name classes starting with caps (`Arrays`), and variables with lowercase letters (`videoGame`).

Comment: I'm not sure you realize how vague your question is. We can't speak to what you can and can't do for the function because we don't know how it's implemented. Additionally, you might look at rephrasing your question because it's unclear what you're looking for

Comment: If `arrays` is a class, does that mean `price` is a `static` variable?  If you take out the word `static`, then the `price` will belong to each object (such as `VideoGame`) rather than to the class (`arrays`).  Maybe that's what you're looking for, but other than that I agree that this is a very vague question.

Comment: Typically a method called `getXyz` would not usually take a parameter, but it would return something. Yours seems to take a parameter and then prints a message. Conventionally, we would name that method `printXyz`. What exactly is your code trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just going to go out on a limb and try to answer as best I can.

Assuming arrays is some custom class you made that just defines two arrays and offers getters/setters for those arrays:

Yes, what you seem to what to do is entirely possible although it seems pointless for all practical application. To do so you would just define a variable named "price" in your arrays class and make it public.

You could then use your exact code

```
arrays.getPrice(VideoGame.price);
```

However, by adding price to arrays this variable is then added to every instance of arrays. This can be avoided by adding the "static" keyword modifier to your new price variable which means that it will be instantiated at most once. Additionally, when you add the static keyword, I believe you no longer need to specify your specific object - meaning your code could now look even like:

```
arrays.getPrice(arrays.price);
```

By making a variable public, you avoid having to make a getter/setter for it, although this is discouraged.